# How do I await a React Hook in Jest?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs, react-hooks

I'm trying to transition a small example from using `shouldComponentUpdate` to using React hooks. I also want to write some unit tests within Jest, which is where I'm struggling.

*Note*: that I've seen some existing questions/answers and I do **not** want to use a `setTimeout` for my testing.

The code I have at the moment looks like this, firstly the component:

```
export default function HelloStarWars(props) {
    const data = useFetch(`https://swapi.co/api/people/${props.id}`);
    const { name } = data;

    return (
        <h1>Hello {name || "..."}!</h1>
    );
}
```

where `useFetch` is defined as follows:

```
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";

export default function useFetch(url) {
    const [data, setData] = useState({});

    async function getData() {
        const response = await fetch(url);
        const data = await response.json();
        setData(data);
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        getData();
    }, []);

    return data;
}
```

Now the actual bit I'm struggling with, is I can't work out how to convert this code that I put together. Essentially I have no `componentDidMount()` function to `await` anymore - so what do I wait upon to ensure that the data has been retrieved?

```
describe("ComponentDidMount", () => {

    beforeEach(() => {
        fetch.resetMocks();
    });

    it("Obtains result and sets data correctly", async () => {
        const wrapper = await mount(<HelloStarWars id="1" />);
        const instance = wrapper.instance();

        fetch.mockResponseOnce(JSON.stringify({ name: 'Jedi Master' }));
        await instance.componentDidMount();

        wrapper.update();

        expect(wrapper).toMatchSnapshot();
    });
});
```

One option I'm aware of is I could, spy on the `useFetch` and mock the return result. I will do that if I have to, but at the moment I like the `jest-fetch-mock` library that I'm using and the capabilities it offers.

Comment: You dont need to await on componentDidMount because it is called as soon as the component is mounted. and since you are rendering it using mount, it will be called instantly

Comment: Thanks @HarshitAgarwal, I've modified the question slightly to hopefully make it clearer. What I want to do is `await` for the fetch result to have completed.

Comment: try with adding `await Promise.resolve()`  instead of `wrapper.update()` - you actually don't need to force update manually instead you have to await till Promise mocked with your `fetch-mock` is resolved.

Comment: @skyboyer what `Promise` should I be awaiting on exactly?

Comment: I believe you just need to flush [microtasks queue](https://blog.bitsrc.io/microtask-and-macrotask-a-hands-on-approach-5d77050e2168) so I mean literally `await Promise.resolve()` that would run all resolved promises(microtasks).

Comment: I'm not really sure if `useEffect` is microtask or macrotask based. if that works and you don't like `magic-like` statement you may found [`flush-promises`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/flush-promises) to be less magic-like. if it does not work then you may try with macrotask(`setTimeout(..., 0)`) instead.

Comment: @skyboyer that kinda works! I get a react warning (logged as an error) `When testing, code that causes React state updates should be wrapped into act(...):` when doing so, but my test did run.

Comment: as for this error it should go away with 16.9: https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/14769